# Material applies to every face rather than entire object

Tags: rendering, texturing

I am trying to apply a material/texture to an entire object (UVSphere), but when I render, it acts as if it is applying to each individual face rather than the whole object.

[image: Sphere with transparent texture dots on every face]

I am trying to do something more like what is depicted here:

[image: Sphere with single transparent texture]

I haven't posted to this forum before. Please let me know if there is more I ought to say/include.

I am trying to imitate procedure described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEsDeNJhvE4&t=282s

The procedure is not UV mapping or using images. It uses a transparent material with a blend type texture to achieve the hole through the sphere and the shift from red to white.

[Here is the blend file I am working with.](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ap5q_85-6r4vi60YX0h2Dj7VNJh0gg)

Comment: I don't believe the steps there are duplicate, but I could be wrong. I should have explained more - I am duplicating procedure described here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEsDeNJhvE4&t=282s - the material is using a blend texture, not image. The idea is to create a transparent spot on one part of the sphere, with white fading to red on the rest.

Comment: perhaps share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Edited posting to include blend file.

Comment: The tutorial uses the  'Generated' texture coordinate space  -- you are using 'UV'

Comment: "Generated Texture" it - how do I mark your comment as the answer? Sorry, new here.